# How to get our Salesforce org ready for APIs?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, post, third-party

I need some guidance to understand how a certain API will work and the process of making it so.

We have a third party online e-learning app (called bksb) where learners do assessments and we manually input the results on their Salesforce record.

bksb have a bunch of APIs ready to use and I need to know how to make our Salesforce org to retrieve (GET) but also (POST) learner's information.

The process would be:

1. On the Learner's record, a status change would trigger bksb (the third party software) to create an account using the learner's SF information (NAME, DOB, EMAIL ADDRESS).

**Using the POST api/users/createUser method**

2. Once the user logs in and completes the assessment, then retrieve the results and pull through to populate fields on the Learners'
   record in Salesforce.

**Using the GET
    api/results/initialAssessment/{userId}/all?page={page}&recordsPerPage={recordsPerPage}
    and
GET api/results/diagnosticAssessment/{userId}/all?page={page}&recordsPerPage={recordsPerPage}**

How would I go about implementing this? What would I need to do from our Salesforce org side?

ANY help is much appreciated!
Natasha :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I go about implementing this?

In general, you need to make callouts from Salesforce to your external services. Now it depends how you want to make the callouts -- using configuration or using custom code.

You can either use [Outbound Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm) to send data to external services or you can use [Apex to make callouts](http://Invoking%20Callouts%20Using%20Apex). Because you have a requirement to update fields back in Salesforce based on the response, my recommendation is to use Apex.

> What would I need to do from our Salesforce org side?

Once you have decided which route you need to take, you need to configure either an outbound message or write custom code along with necessary configurations required to make callouts.

Take a look at these resources which will help you get started in this direction:

- [Understanding Outbound Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_understanding.htm)
- [Invoking Callouts Using Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts.htm)
- [Named Credentials as Callout Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)